# Is it possible to display the row of 2 in the power of 1,2...10 (the biggest) using while loop with Math.pow?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, pow

Here is my code that doesn`t work. It seems to me that it has to but when I use console (in inspect section in the browser) nothing happens, it doesn`t find any bug.

I`d be very thankful if you explain me where is the mistake(-s)

```
var counter = 0;
var result = Math.pow (2, counter);
    while (result < Math.pow (2, 10)) {
    console.log(result);
    counter = counter + 1;
    }
```

Comment: You are changing counter in your while but never changing result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As juvian stated in the comments, you're updating the variable "counter" in your while loop, but you also need to update "result" in every loop as well. Here's a revised version of your code with an explanation.

```
// Counter starts at zero
var counter = 0;

/*
    Result needs to be initialized to check the
    initial condition.

    Alternatively, we could have changed the
    condition of the while loop to something like:
    while (counter <= 10) { ... }

    (this would be technically faster because
     you're not re-computing Math.pow(2,10))
*/
var result = 0;

// We perform the code in here until the condition is false
while (result < Math.pow (2, 10)) {
    // First, we raise 2 to the power of counter (0 the first time)
    var result = Math.pow (2, counter);
    // Print the result
    console.log(result);
    // Now increment the counter
    // (this will change what the first line of the loop does)
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: how the loop will start if it doesn`t know what the result is (and therefore whether it`s greater or less than Math.pow (2, 10))?

Comment: Oh, you raise a good point. You could initialize result to zero to correct this. I'll edit my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of writing this would be:

```
var result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(function (num) {
  return Math.pow(2, num)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The incremented counter is never used in result computation. Try this.

```
var counter = 0;
while (Math.pow (2, counter) < Math.pow (2, 10)) {
  console.log(Math.pow (2, counter));
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```